# Uninstalled Smart Thermostat wiring now AC won’t turn on. Please help!

Tags: electrical

I disconnected my previously working ecobee to go back to traditional non WiFi Honeywell thermostat that was installed before the ecobee3.

The Heat works good but when I try to turn on AC it just won’t kick on. Thinking I connected the, back incorrectly, can’t seem to figure it out. I attached an image of my thermostat wiring and furnace wiring.

The AC common wire (white) is going to T terminal since I don’t have a C. 
The AC Y (Red) wire is going to the Y terminal.

Any advice it tips would be greatly appreciated.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you post a photo of the wiring at the thermostat end?

Comment: Which wires were connected to the controlled contacts on the thermostst you removed? Those are the wires that should be connected to the contacts on the replacement stat...

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I have included a photo of the thermostat wiring.

Comment: When I disconnect the AC wiring I was able to ensure the other four terminal points at the furnace panel board and the thermostat  matched. Now I am having trouble determining how the AC should be hooked back up.

Comment: First thing I suggest is to shorten the copper without insulation on the thermostat - a short waiting to happen...

Comment: @SolarMike I had a photo of the connections that unfortunately was lost on a previous phone. When I made the connections back from the ecobee it had the different wiring setup because I didn’t have a C terminal so I think it’s possible I confused it.

Comment: Thank you, shortening cooper wire. Check!

Comment: Updated with better photos and copper wire trimmed on thermostat.

Comment: What it the make and model; of the thermostat? Look up it's wiring guide online.